# Custom confirmation pop-up to admin form "Save" button

Tags: magento2

I have a module with `Block\Adminhtml` files and in one of those files it adds the Save button as follows:

```
$this->buttonList->add(
    'save_and_continue_edit',
    [
        'class' => 'save',
        'label' => __('Save and Continue Edit'),
        'data_attribute' => [
            'mage-init' => ['button' => ['event' => 'saveAndContinueEdit', 'target' => '#edit_form']],
        ]
    ],
    10
);
```

I added `'onclick' => "alert('test')"` there and it works,
now I need a little bit more complex logic for the confirmation, so my question is how can I define a JS function and make it available there? Like `'onclick' => "customConfirmFunction()"` which can get the event and do `e.preventDefault()` if needed too.

This module also has a `requirejs-config.js` file with a map inside `view/frontend` but I'm pretty new in magento so no idea how it plays out.

Comment: I was able to load a JS file with `deps` in `requirejs-config.js` but that function I defined is not available outside

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native JS confirm popup:

```
'onclick' => "if (confirm('test')) {event.preventDefault(); /* doStuff */}"
```

Check the following links for more information:

- [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp)
- [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8614559/15443986)

Comment: It won't work because I want more complex logic before I show up the confirm, so I would need a custom function there.

Comment: Try to add a js file in the `view/adminhtml/js` area and you can add a new `requirejs-config` for the admin area or use the naming `Vendor_Module/js/yourfile` and add your event listener on the file, I have not tested that but it should work. Check the file for similar behavior: `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Tab/Attributes/Create.php@_beforeToHtml()`